# Proofs using the Axioms of Probability

Tags: probability, axioms

I need to prove that

$$P(A \backslash B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$$

and

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

using the axioms of probability but can't see where to start. Note: this is homework, so a hint only would be nice :)

Comment: Corrected question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Think "countable additivity". What can you say about $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ if you are hoping to use this axiom.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

Let $B \subset A$, then $A = B \cup (A \setminus B)$ which is a disjoint union so...

Now,
$$A \cup B = (A \setminus (A \cap B)) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus (A \cap B))$$
which is again a disjoint union. So...

Answer (score 1):

The second one as written is false.  I'm sure you meant

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Jonas' answer is a good hint on how to apply the first part to prove the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Proof The events A\B, B \A and A∩B are pairwise disjoint and their union is A∪B. By Axiom 3
 P(A∪B) = P(A\B) +P(B\A) +P(A∩B) (1) 
Axiom 3 also implies that
 P(A) = P(A\B) +P(A∩B) 
so P(A\B) = P(A)−P(A∩B), (2) 
and P(B) = P(B\A) +P(A∩B) 
so P(B) = P(B\A) +P(A∩B). (3) 
We can now substitute equations (2) and (3) into (1) to obtain 
P(A∪B) = P(A) +P(B)−P(A∩B).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.